# Ruby Enumerator "Single" method

Tags: ruby, monkeypatching, enumerable, refinements

I really need to make use of something similar to the [Single](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155325(v=vs.110).aspx) method, which:

> Returns the only element of a sequence, and throws an exception if there is not exactly one element in the sequence.

Obviously I can add an extension/refinement for convenience.

But does something similar already exists?
Maybe in ActiveSupport or other library?

Answer (score 2):

No, nothing in the Standard Library (nor ActiveSupport, I believe), but easy enough to implement.

```
module EnumeratorWithSingle
  class TooManyValuesException < StandardError; end
  class NotEnoughValuesException < StandardError; end

  refine Enumerator do
    def single
      val = self.next
      begin
        self.next
        raise TooManyValuesException
      rescue StopIteration
        val
      end
    rescue StopIteration
      raise NotEnoughValuesException
    end
  end
end

module Test
  using EnumeratorWithSingle    
  puts [1].each.single            # 1
  puts [1, 2].each.single         # EnumeratorWithSingle::TooManyValuesException
end
```

Comment: `e = [1, 2].each;  e.next;  puts e.single` prints 2, which may not be the desired result.

Comment: That's a nice way of dealing with the problem, but don't you mean to have `begin` as the first line of `single`? Right now, if `self #=> [].to_enum`, `self.next` will raise a `StopIteration` exception that won't be handled.

Comment: @sreenslag makes an interesting point. Perhaps the first line of `single` should be `self_cpy = dup` and then operate on `self.cpy`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: `begin...end` is optional at the `def` level. Note the indentation. `StopIteration` is handled in each case (including for `[].each.single`); try it for yourself.

Comment: @steenslag: OP explicitly asked for `Enumerator#single`, and `Enumerator` may or may not be rewindable. Thus you don't really have a choice. To me, `Enumerator#single` should say "there is a single value remaining in the enumerator". If you want to test whether a container has a single value, that should belong to `Enumerable#single`, as you know `self.each` will give you the whole sequence.

Comment: Amadan, I was wondering about the indentation. I didn't know that. Thanks for setting me straight. Consider adding `puts [].each.single` to your `Test` module.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: It's not a proper test module as the next line would not be reachable due to the exception :) But yeah, if that line executed, you would get `EnumeratorWithSingle::NotEnoughValuesException`.